# uiRouter: '10 $digest() iterations reached' during $state.go(...) in changeStateStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have router configured like this:

```
function Router($injector) {
    $injector.get('$locationProvider').html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
    $injector.get('$stateProvider')
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/login/login.html'
        })
        .state('auth', {
            abstract: true,
            templateUrl: 'app/layout/layout.html'
        })
        .state('auth.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
            auth: true
        });

   $injector.get('$urlRouterProvider').otherwise('/home');
}
```

and `run` block configured like this:

```
function stateChangeHandler(event, toState, toParams) {
    var injector = this.$injector;

    function inject(name) {
        return injector.get(name);
    }

    if (
        toState.auth && 
        !inject('AuthService').isAuthenticated()
    ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        inject('$state').go('login');
    } else if (
        !toState.auth &&
        inject('AuthService').isAuthenticated()
    ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        inject('$state').go('auth.home');
    }
}

function RouterRun($injector) {
    $injector.get('$rootScope').$on('$stateChangeStart',
        stateChangeHandler.bind({
            $injector: $injector
        }));
}
```

//UPDATED

all together :

```
angular.module('router', ['ui.router'])
    .config(Router)
    .run(RouterRun);

angular.module('app', [..., 'router']);
```

and when I type just host in address bar like this `172.16.16.114:8080` and user isn't authenticated then I get

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:14346)
at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:14571)
at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1455)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4203)
at doBootstrap (angular.js:1453)
at bootstrap (angular.js:1473)
at angularInit (angular.js:1367)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:26304)
at jQuery.Callbacks.fire (jquery.js:3099)
```

but in the end I reach the target `login` page with address in bar `172.16.16.114:8080/login`

I can't find out why this error occurs. Please help with any suggestions.

Comment: This is pretty easy to solve. Please add your View (HTML), so we can help ya.

Comment: @lin What exactly View(template) would you like to look at?

Comment: I want to know, how and when your `functions` are called.

Comment: @lin, added 'all together' sinppet.

Comment: Thanks, Ill take a look on this. Right after breakfast. Stay on.

Comment: You have so long breakfast on Mars, @lin.

Comment: Haha, ya. Sun takes 24h to get up ;). Could you create a plunker? Wasn't able to reproduce. :(

Comment: @lin, this [one](http://plnkr.co/edit/lOuq2HZ06lw8kam2QMAl?p=preview). The issue occurs when I try use `templateUrl` instead `template` in routing. Look at comments there.

Comment: Thanks. Tried, but the error does not come up. Commented in/out the blocks you told. What I'am doing wrong?

Comment: @lin, yes, in plunker console I also don't see any error, if to commented out `template` /in `templateUrl`,  but and code doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Lets move to the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79321/ya-help-me-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeoman gulp-angular generator creates gulp tasks which doesn't include generated template cache module in html by default, so all requests for templates are sent to server, not through cache module. After changes in gulp task by adding generated file in landing html issue was resolved.